# Spring MVC - Ajax call returns an HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, ajax, http, spring-mvc

I would like to submit form data to the controller but even though I see in HTTP request that the parameters are being send I get a 415 HTTP error.
Here is my JQuery/AJAX call to the controller:

```
$.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            url: "calculate",
            data : JSON.stringify(data),
            success : function(response){
                alert("OK");
            },
            error : function(){
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

And here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "calculate", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody void calculate (@RequestBody QueryElements queryElements, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("OK");
}
```

Now what happens is that if I remove the @RequestBody in the controller I see in debug that the controller is being called, but obviously I need to keep the annotation.

Here is the HTTP request:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:593
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=AD8FEA2E46709554189D687A7C65929D
Host:localhost:9082
Origin:http://localhost:9082
Referer:http://localhost:9082/cheexport/export?
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
{"bindListregInc":"","bindListregEsc":"","bindListprovInc":"","bindListprovEsc":"","bindListcomInc":"","bindListcomEsc":"","bindListcapInc":"","bindListcapEsc":"","bindListsitInc":"","bindListsitEsc":"","stringaInclusa":"","stringaEsclusa":"","consenso":"","clausola1c":"","sponsor":"","bindListcontrInc":"","bindListcontrEsc":"","bindListcliInc":"","bindListcliEsc":"","nomeContratto":"","customQuote":"","campiHeaderHidden":""}
```

Comment: Can you share QueryElements class? and try sending request using Postman or any RestApiclient which will help in understanding if issue is in Ajax call or in controller

Comment: May be JSON.stringify(data) is not sending request in correct way, try hardcoding like `data : '{"bindListregInc":"","bindListregEsc":"","bindListprovInc":"","bindListprovEsc":"","bindListcomInc":"","bindListcomEsc":"","bindListcapInc":"","bindListcapEsc":"","bindListsitInc":"","bindListsitEsc":"","stringaInclusa":"","stringaEsclusa":"","consenso":"","clausola1c":"","sponsor":"","bindListcontrInc":"","bindListcontrEsc":"","bindListcliInc":"","bindListcliEsc":"","nomeContratto":"","customQuote":"","campiHeaderHidden":""}',`

Comment: In this way I get a '404 Bad Request'

Comment: Can you share your server logs

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a void calculate method when you expect a JSON.
Try to return something:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "calculate", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> calculate (@RequestBody QueryElements queryElements, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
}
```

Comment: No, it's the same. The point is that it doesn't even being capture by the controller, while when I remove the @RequestBody it does

Answer (score 0):

At your @RequestMapping annotation you should add consumes="application/json"
Like this:
    @RequestMapping(value = "someUrl", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})

This going to tell Spring that Method accepts applicatin/json requests.

Or you could try to use @RestController instead of @Controller

Also try to add "contentType" to the JS code. 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api1/tax",
        data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
        type: method,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            setTimeout(reloadTable, globalTimeout);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

Comment: I added the "consumes" property, and I have no changes

Comment: Could leave this change with "consumes" and add to the JavaScript code below:     $.ajax({
                        url: "/api1/tax",
                        data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
                        type: method,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    }); Instead of Header parameter put contentType